# Is it possible to retrieve all channel IDs from one country using the YouTube Data API

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I am quite successfully using the YouTube Data API in Java. I can retrieve all the channel Infos and video Infos I need etc. But I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve ALL channel IDs from one country or at least the top 100 channels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using /search endpoint.

Sample request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&order=date&regionCode=SG&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Note - maximum results you can get is 50. If you need 100 records, then have to use next page access token